# How can I convert Anonymous type to Ttype?

Tags: c#

How can I use Cast() Extension method for above conversion?

e.g.

```
var aType = anonymousType;

IEnumreable<MyType> = aType.Cast();
```

Solved By

```
aType.Select(i => new MyType { } ).ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I'm not quite sure about your purpose. Any LINQ query shoudl return an IEnumerable<T> object, even using anonymous types.

Comment: Note: The .ToList() is only required if you want the result to be an actual list (i.e. all conversions done at once) instead of an enumerator that does the conversion on the fly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only type that you can cast an anonymous type to is `Object`. If you want any other type, you have to create those objects from the data in the anonymously typed objects.

Example:

```
List<MyType> items = aType.Select(t => new MyType(t.Some, t.Other)).ToList();
```

You should consider to create the `MyType` objects already when you get the data, instead of creating anonymously typed objects.

Comment: Agreed.  It's hard to think of a scenario where this wouldn't be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Is `aType` is an `IEnumerable<anonymous type>` returned by e.g. a linq query?

You might want to use `Select` (which applies a transformation function to an element) insted of `Cast` which just performs a cast.

```
IEnumerable<MyType> = aCollection.Select(e => SomeExpressionWithE);
```

Comment: The function is in the lambda body of the select method that Dario wrote. For example, let's say that you had an anonymous type representing a person with two fields, Name (of type String) and Id (of a custom type EmployeeId). If you wanted a new IEnumerable<EmployeeId>, you could write list.Select(e => e.Id).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that may help you. Although I think Guffa is right, you should create an instance of your class whenever you need them. Anonymous types are not meant to be used that way.

Here's the link:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/castinganonymous.aspx

Answer (score -2):

```
IEnumreable<MyType> n = (IEnumreable<MyType>)aType;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Comment: That only works if the object already implements the interface, and then you don't need the cast at all.